# Store keys of all users in keychain without overriding others in iOS xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, keychain

I want to store the RSA key pair of user logged in to my iOS application but at this way that the key can be differentiated with other user. I write a code for that but it overrides the key after each login.

Here is the code:

```
 +(BOOL)storeRSAComponentInKeychain:(NSData*)keyPairComponent keyAttrClass:(CFStringRef)keyAttrClass {
    NSMutableDictionary* keychainItem = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    keychainItem[(__bridge id)kSecClass] = (__bridge id)kSecClassKey;
    keychainItem[(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType] = (__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA;
    keychainItem[(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyClass] = (__bridge id)keyAttrClass;
    keychainItem[(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessible] = (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked;
    keychainItem[(__bridge id)kSecAttrIsPermanent] = @YES;
    keychainItem[(__bridge id)kSecReturnPersistentRef] = @YES;
    keychainItem[(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag] = [self secItemTagDataForKAttrClass:keyAttrClass];
    keychainItem[(__bridge id)kSecValueData] = keyPairComponent;

    return [self storeItemInKeychain:keychainItem];
}
```

Is there anyway that I can dynamically generate the attribute for saving key like RSA_username and save the respective key in that attribute of keychain, So that I can easily fetch the key of desired user. Or any other way to implement it. Please help, I am new to iOS development.

Comment: so -- to clarify -- your app will allow multiple different users and you want to save each RSA key pair for each of those different users?

Comment: Yes.. It allow multiple users and I want to store the RSA key pair of all users and access only the RSA key pair which is associated to that logged in user.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Any Help??